# $Created_x0020_Date.ifnew what are the rules

Tags: list, xml, item

I have the following coming back when I look at the xml for my view:

```
$Created_x0020_Date.ifnew
```

This indicates if an item is new or not. What are the rules in determining if an item is new or not? A client is asking and I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is very simple. Each SPWebApplication has a property which specify how many days the icon should be shown. To get using PowerShell :

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://sharepoint
$wa.DaysToShowNewIndicator
```